# Webmethods get type of document reference from IData

Tags: java, webmethods

I'm using webmethods java service to write a simple parser and I want to know if its possible to know the referenced type of the document passed in pipeline?

For example I have a document passed to the java service and it has a document reference inside, for example BudgetCategory docType. Is there any way to get the reference document Name or type or anything that refers to BudgetCategory?

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately not possible. At runtime you do not have any information about document types in your pipeline, this information is just available at design time. The only way is to pass the doc type name of the top level document into your service, too. Then you can use the IntegrationServer API to parse the doc type and any referenced doc types. But you have to hard code your doc type name, are deduct this somehow from your runtime data.

Comment: Yup, I managed to do it by creating a factory service which will pass the whole relational structure of the document to my java service and it will build the query using that... thanks anywa